# face_recognition.compare_faces return only false

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition, python

I wanna make script that get an image of face and return all images in dataset that it found in.
I saved encodings of all images in dataset and load it into a list:

```
dataEncodingsList = [d["encoding"] for d in data]
```

Than I make encodings also to the image with face to search:

```
imageEncodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(image, boxes)
```

And than I try to compare between the encodings:

```
for encoding in imageEncodings:
        # attempt to match each face in the input image to our known encodings
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(dataEncodingsList,
            encoding[0],tolerance=0.6)
```

but its not recognize any image. I tried to change the tolerance up and down and it didnt help.
I printed the return value from compare_faces and got only "false":

```
print (matches)
=>  [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, ..., False]
```

someone can help please?

Comment: Did you have the same result when you lower the `tolerance`?

Comment: Yes, even when I try tolerance = 0.1.... and there are many pictures of that face

Comment: I am also facing same

Answer (score 2):

Add for loop to check encoding in list of encodings

```
for encoding in imageEncodings:
    for j in range(len(dataEncodingsList)):
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(dataEncodingsList,encoding,tolerance=0.6)
```